# Merging and Counting of attributes uisng Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I have grouped 2 columns of a CSV file
`(r3 = df.groupby(['Predicted_Label', 'Actual_Label']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (r3))` 
to get the following result:
[image: Groupby count of dataframe]

Column 5 and 6 of Actual Labels should be merged into Row 1 of Predicted Labels.
Output should be in the following form:
[image]
How to create the above new columns using Pandas?

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: I didn't get b & c!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new columns created by [`numpy.diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) and subtracted `sum`s per rows and per columns, [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is used for same indices of columns like index values:

```
#strip traling whitespaces
df['Predicted_Label'] = df['Predicted_Label'].str.strip()

r3 = df.groupby(['Predicted_Label', 'Actual_Label']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

a = np.diagonal(r3.reindex(columns=r3.index))
b = r3.sum(axis=1) - a
c = r3.sum().reindex(r3.index) - a

out = r3.assign(T1=a,T2=b,T3=c)
print (out)
    0   1   2     3   5   6    T1   T2   T3
0  14   0   3    22   0   0    14   25   14
1   5  56  14   157  19  11    56  206    8
2   2   0  37    26   0   0    37   28   17
3   7   8   0  1805   0   1  1805   16  205
```

Comment: What changes should I make to `r3 = df.groupby(['Predicted_Label', 'Actual_Label']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)` , so as to continue with `np.diagonal(df.reindex(columns=df.index))`. ? On running `pd.Index([r3])`, output is `Index([[' ', '0', '1', '2']]`

Comment: How  to change output of from  `Index([[' ', '0', '1', '2']])` to `(Index[['0', '1', '2', '3']]`? Since output of `a = np.diagonal(df.reindex(columns=df.index))` is NAN, which is not as desired?

Comment: I want another column ,which is described as follows T4 :(T1/(T1+T2)). I have tried this s = a+b and d = a/s.It is working for me. Is there any better method to achieve the same?

Comment: Thank You. Your assistance was of great help.

Comment: @Satyam Kumar Your method is really good, if want one line use `d = a/(a + b)`.